# Bugged CSS Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, scroll

[As you can see on this page](http://devsite.doskosport.com/index.php?dispatch=categories.view&category_id=124), having the mouse hover's over a product picture:

There is a box that shows up and has a scroll.
For some reason the scroll jumps right back up.

Any suggestions?

If there is any interference from JavaScript, what's the best way to locate it?

I'm having doubts about this lines here, might this be the problem?
(IE reports errors there, for not founding the `mveditbox`

```
if(browserName == "Netscape"){
  (...)
}else{
  var stop = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  window.onscroll=mveditbox;
}
```

Comment: Try to make a minimal example that show the same behavior and put it in a jsFiddle. It is a lot of work to dig through all the code.

Comment: it looks something is forcing scroller to goes up after half second.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a `return false;` to the call to the javascript that opens the modal.

I cant see clearly the call to it, you may want to put it in a JsFiddle, but if its a call like this:

```
<a id="product pic" href="#" onclick="modal();">
```

you need to change it to this

```
<a id="product pic" href="#" onclick="modal(); return false;">
```

However, if you want to change it for all mouseovers in the document, you can try adding this jquery

```
document.getElementById('YOURPRODUCTPIC').addEventListener('mouseover',function YOURMODALFUNCTION(){/*do stuff here*/}, false);
```

Comment: @raff the code is the following: html:`onmouseover="quick({$product.product_id},{$i});disp({$product.product_id},{$i});return false;" onmouseout="hide({$product.product_id},{$i});return false;"`

Comment: js: `function disp(id,val){
  var ele = document.getElementById("div"+val);
     var top = 0;
     var left = 0;
   while(ele.tagName != "BODY") {
         top += ele.offsetTop;
         left += ele.offsetLeft;
         ele = ele.offsetParent;
   }`